# Capturing the user input without requiring "Enter"

Tags: bash, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, signals, read

I have the following task:

The scripts prompts user for parameters and in the end, runs a certain command based on those parameters. (Imagine the script, which prompts first for the filename, then for arguments for the `chmod`).

The problem is, that the script must be terminated by certain key sequence (like when the user types halt without enter, instead of, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>).

Comment: Is the problem that you need your program to run in the background and get user input, or that you want to read the input without requiring the user to hit enter?  The title seems to suggest one, but the question seems more like the other and they're likely to have very different answers

Comment: Program to be able to capture regular user input (with enter) for filling the variables, and at the same time, sequence like "halt" to quit the script (break loop)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `read` with `-n 1` to read character by character and build up the string that you've read as you go.  Then you can decide what to do each character as it comes in:

```
val=""
while read -n 1 char; do
    if [[ $char = "" ]]; then
        printf 'Got an enter and the string is %s' "$val"
        # do whatever else you want with it here
        val="" # reset it to get the next param
    else
        val="$val$char" # append input
    fi
    if [[ $val = "halt" ]]; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: What about at any time? Plus, I have to reuse it on like 5 parameters

Comment: @rkhunter you could use this to process the parameters, as each time you get the enter thing you could store `val` wherever you want or do whatever you need to with that parameter.  As far as reading at any arbitrary time during the execution, if you need that bash is probably not the right language for your task

Comment: The UI requirement stated by OP is bizarre. This is the closest mechanism that will get you anywhere. If the user has typed "H A L" you don't yet know if that input is for a field, or the special "HALT" command. You can't get around handling key-by-key and doing your own (bizarre) logic, as far as I can see. Sometimes the best solution is to fix the requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Given the description of the task, you aren't supposed to handle input character by character. Reading it line by line is fine. Reading character by character won't help you.

If you don't need to do anything on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> other than exiting the script, then don't do anything. That's the default behavior.

If you need to run some custom code on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (which may or may not end by quitting the script), there's a built-in mechanism in the terminal driver. Pressing this key [sends the signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#Sending_signals) [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT). In the shell, define a [trap](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-trap) for the signal.

```
cleanup () {
  … whatever you need to do before the script exits …
}
trap 'echo >&2 "Aborting"; cleanup; exit 130' INT
while IFS= read -r line; do
  …
done
```

Comment: How would that handle exiting when the user types "halt" without hitting enter?

Comment: @EricRenouf It wouldn't, but that request is based on a misinterpretation of the task. It would be an awful user interface (press `h`, `a`, `l`, `t`, oops I meant “hallo”, dammit why did the script exit instead of letting me press BackSpace then `o`‽).

Comment: Ok, I absolutely agree it'd make for a terrible interface, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something about how this all fit together